# Freeform: How do I detect if a form was submitted?

Tags: plugin-freeform, freeform

I'm need to send a google analytics tracking event when a form is submitted. To do that, I need to know on any page of the site if a user has landed there as a result of a form being submitted.

Given that the client can create their own forms, I can't rely on URL parameters, and it could be any form, so I can't set the form handle manually.

How do I detect if any form was submitted?
Freeform's docs explicitly name a form handle, which isn't a dynamic approach ( https://docs.solspace.com/craft/freeform/v3/template-functions/freeform.submissions.html#usage-in-templates ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could do this is on the backend via a module and the FreeForm events:

1. Run `composer require ramsey/uuid` in the root directory of your project
2. Add the following lines to the top of `modules/Module.php` right after the line that says `use Craft;`

```
use yii\base\Event;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;
use Solspace\Freeform\Services\FormsService;
use Solspace\Freeform\Events\Forms\AfterSubmitEvent;
```

3. Add the following in the Module's `init()` method, right after the line that says `// Custom initialization code goes here...`:

```
Event::on(
    FormsService::class,
    FormsService::EVENT_AFTER_SUBMIT,
    static function(AfterSubmitEvent $event) {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $submission = $event->getSubmission();

        $uuid4 = Uuid::uuid4();

        $client = new Client();
        $client->post('https://www.google-analytics.com/collect', [
            'headers' => [
                'User-Agent' => Craft::$app->request->getUserAgent(),
            ],
            'query' => [
                'v' => 1,
                'tid' => 'REPLACE-THIS',      // Tracking ID from GA
                'cid' => $uuid4->toString(),
                't'   => 'event',
                'ec'  => 'REPLACE-THIS',      // Event Category
                'ea'  => 'REPLACE-THIS',      // Event Action
                'el'  => 'REPLACE-THIS',      // Event Label
            ]
        ]);
    }
);
```

4. Replace the `REPLACE-THIS` strings with your own Tracking ID and Event options
5. Uncomment the following line in `config/app.php`:

```
//'bootstrap' => ['my-module'],
```

*Tip: You have the form and the submission available to you as `$form` and `$submission` respectively in case you want to use any of their values to populate your Event options (i.e. use the form name as the Event Label or something).*

---

Hopefully that helps! (Disclaimer: I just threw this together so it's not really "tested"  - if you do run into issues ping me on Discord and I'll help you get it working.)